# Why $b_0$ and $b_1$ from linear regression $(y = b_0 + b_1\cdot x)$ are calculated like follows? How is the formula for such variables derived?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, least-squares, linear-regression

I can't understand the logic of the following formula $$b_1 = \displaystyle\frac{\sum(x-\overline{x})\cdot(y-\overline{y})}{\sum(x-\overline{x})^2 }$$ where $\overline{x}$ and $\overline{y}$ are arithmetic means of $x$ and $y$, respectively. And if we calculated $b_1$, why do we choose next formula for calculating $b_0$? $$\overline{y} = b_0 + b_1\cdot\overline{x}$$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: They decide in advance that they want a formula of the form $y=b_0+b_1x.$  Then they compute the values of $b_0$ and $b_1$ so that the line will fit the data best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These values for the slope and the y-intercept  of the regression line are found by the least square method.

They find the line for which the sum of the squared errors are minimized.

The method requires taking partial derivatives of the sum squared errors and solve for those constants by making the partial derivatives equal $0.$

Comment: thank you for directing

Comment: Thanks for your attention.

Comment: But, why we can't just use absolute values of errors (distance from point to line) ? Why we need to compare exactly squares not just absolute values from each side of line ?

Comment: Absolute values are not differentiable so we can not minimize it easily.